# Boolean expression as template argument

Tags: c++, c++11, template-specialization, sfinae, boolean-expression

I'm trying to set the resolution of a timer class using a bit of template metaprogramming. Here's a bit of a problem which has got me a little stumped. The boolean expression passed as argument is being disregarded.

```
// Boolean SFINAE struct for partial specialization selection.
template< bool T > struct SFINAE_void;
template<> struct SFINAE_void< true >  { using type = void; };
template<> struct SFINAE_void< false > {};

/* Precision selector */
template< std::intmax_t , std::intmax_t , typename=void > 
struct ChosenResolution;

template< std::intmax_t NUM, std::intmax_t DEN > 
struct ChosenResolution< NUM, DEN, 
typename SFINAE_void< 
( real_cast(NUM)/real_cast(DEN) <  real_cast(1.0) && 
  real_cast(NUM)/real_cast(DEN) >= real_cast(10^-3) ) >::type > {
   using type = std::chrono::milliseconds;
};

template< std::intmax_t NUM, std::intmax_t DEN > 
struct ChosenResolution< NUM, DEN,
typename SFINAE_void< 
( real_cast(NUM)/real_cast(DEN) <  real_cast(10^-3) && 
  real_cast(NUM)/real_cast(DEN) >= real_cast(10^-6) ) >::type > {
   using type = std::chrono::microseconds;
};

template< std::intmax_t NUM, std::intmax_t DEN > 
struct ChosenResolution< NUM, DEN, 
typename SFINAE_void< 
( real_cast(NUM)/real_cast(DEN) <  real_cast(10^-6) && 
  real_cast(NUM)/real_cast(DEN) >= real_cast(10^-9) ) >::type > {
   using type = std::chrono::nanoseconds;
};
```

Debug output shows me that the resolution is `10^-9`. However, `std::chrono::milliseconds` is being chosen as the resolution, instead of `std::chrono::nanoseconds`.

Two questions:

1.) Why?

2.) Slightly divergent - but can a normal, everyday laptop really boast of nanosecond resolution (I am using a steady clock)?

Comment: How is `real_cast` defined?

Comment: `real_cast` is simply a macro for `static_cast< double >`. Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said by skypjack, we need the definition of `real_cast()`.

But I suspect that your problem isn't about SFINAE but about numeric operations.

What do you think is `10^-3`?

Do you think that, as in LaTeX, is the `10` raised to `-3`?

That is the float number `0.001`?

No.

It's the `xor` bit-to-bit operation between integer numbers.

So `10^-3` is `-9`, `10^-6` is `-16` and `10^-9` is `-3`.

An example

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
 {
   std::cout << (10^-3) << std::endl; // print -9
   std::cout << (10^-6) << std::endl; // print -16
   std::cout << (10^-9) << std::endl; // print -3
 }
```

Anyway... if I'm not wrong, you don't need `SFINAE_void`; you can use `std::enable_if` with default type parameter.

Comment: Thank you! Very elementary error. Yes, I see it now :)